# Backbone JS Prefetch JSON with Parent and Child Collection

Tags: json, backbone.js

Initially when my app loads I want to populate all data using the collection "Reset" so I don't have to do an initial AJAX call and fetch the data.

I have two models 2 models for Backbone, a blog and a comment. A blog has a list of comments, this is how my JSON looks.

How do I go about loading this properly into a Backbone collection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass either Backbone Models, or raw JSON into your `reset` call.  So this is one option:

```
collection.reset( [ { 
    title: "A blog post", 
    comments: [ 
        { author: "someone" },
        { author: "someone else" }
    ]
}, {
    title: "Another blog post"
} ] );
```

And this is another, if you have pre-defined models to use:

```
collection.reset( [
    new BlogModel( { 
        title: "A blog post", 
        comments: [ 
            new CommentModel( { author: "someone" } ),
            new CommentModel( { author: "someone else" } )
        ]
    } ),
    new BlogModel( {
        title: "Another blog post"
    } )
] );
```

**Edit**

If you have raw JSON and want to create the typed models, then you can always just use a loop.  Say you have the above raw JSON in an object like "blogs".

```
var models = [];
// iterate through the blogs in the raw JSON, and add them as BlogModels
_.each(blogs, function(blog) {
    var blogModel = new BlogModel(blog);

    // create each comment as a CommentModel, and add back to the BlogModel
    blogModel.set("comments",
        _.map(blogModel.get("comments"), function(comment) {
            return new CommentModel(comment);
        });
    });
    models.push(blogModel);
});
var collection = new Backbone.Collection();

// finally, create the collection using the models
collection.reset(models);
```

Here is an example that runs:  http://jsfiddle.net/8nLCs/8/

Comment: looks ok... however I would not be defining the blog model up front.  I just have a raw JSON list, would I have to loop over each parent object and explicitly instantiate a comment model?

Comment: @aherrick no, you can always just pass in the raw JSON list (as in the first example I listed -- no models, just the JSON representation).

Comment: but then i'll lose the context of the Backbone models right? i'm trying to figure out how to get the goodness of the backbone model without having to manually create each blog/comment model.

Comment: @aherrick you can always write a loop to go through the raw JSON and convert to typed models.  Sort of seems like there should be a better way, but this way works ... see my update above, and updated demo.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
var CommentsCollection
  , PostModel
  , PostsCollection
  , posts
  , blogData;


CommentsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({});


PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    this.comments = new CommentsCollection;
    this.comments.post = this;
    this.on("change:comments", this.updateComments);
    this.updateComments();
  },

  updateComments: function() {
    this.comments.reset(this.get("comments"));
  }

});

PostsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: PostModel
});

blogData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "My Post1",
    comments: [
      {id: 1, message: "Test message 1"},
      {id: 2, message: "Test message 2"}
    ]
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    title: "My Post 2",
    comments: [
      {id: 3, message: "Test message 3"},
      {id: 4, message: "Test message 4"}
    ]
  }
];

posts = new PostsCollection;
posts.reset(blogData);

console.log(posts.get(1).comments.pluck("message"));
```